# Is try catch good to control the flow of my app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, try-catch

I want to update an array of IDs in a firestore document each time I add other documents to the collection.

And if the document does not exist yet (for the creation of the collection), create the document with the ID I want to add as the first value of that array.

So I want to try to update the document everytime and catch a possible error that would be "*Some requested document was not found*" and in that case create the document

as you can see here

```dart
void addDocument(Map<String, dynamic> docData, String docId) {
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  db.collection(docId.trim().toLowerCase()).add(docData).then((value) {
    try {
      db.collection(docId).doc("doclist").update({
        "list": FieldValue.arrayUnion([docData["id"]]),
      });
    } catch (_) {
      Map<String, List<String>> listdata = {
        "list": [docData["id"]],
      };
      db.collection(docId).doc("doclist").set(data);
    }
  });
}
```

So I wonder if it's a "clean" way of doing it, are try/catch are  made to be used that way.

Or should I check if the doc exists with the doc.exists getter ? Since this fonction will be used quite often it would double the number of requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`try catch` should be used for handling exceptions, which typically are not part of your normal flow control.

In this case for example, you can use `set` with its merge option to create-or-update the document:

```
db.collection(docId).doc("doclist").set({
  "list": FieldValue.arrayUnion([docData["id"]]),
}, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

This will create the document with a single item in the array if it didn't exist yet, or otherwise will add the item to the array of the pre-existing document. For more on this, see the second example in the documentation on [setting a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document).